# Export All appointments and meetings (including recurring meetings) Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I need to export a list of the appointments and meetings that I have every week, I am currently using the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Outlook_calendaritemsexport()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Sheet6.Select

'clearing old dates
Range("A2:E2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("G4").Select

Dim FromDateWEEK As Date
Dim ToDateWEEK As Date
Dim FromDateDAY As Date
Dim ToDateDAY As Date

FromDateWEEK = Cells(2, 8).Value
ToDateWEEK = Cells(2, 9).Value

Dim o As Outlook.Application, R As Long
Set o = New Outlook.Application

Dim ons As Outlook.Namespace
Set ons = o.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Dim myfol As Outlook.Folder
Set myfol = ons.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)

Dim myapt As Outlook.AppointmentItem
Dim outRecurrencePattern As Object

Range("A1:D1").Value = Array("Subject", "Start", "End", "Project", "Duration (Hrs)")
R = 1

For Each myapt In myfol.Items

    If (myapt.Start >= FromDateWEEK And myapt.Start <= ToDateWEEK) Then
    
           'Loop through recurring events for this appointment
                    R = R + 1
                    Cells(R, 1).Value = myapt.Subject
                    Cells(R, 2).Value = myapt.Start
                    Cells(R, 3).Value = myapt.End
                    Cells(R, 4).Value = myapt.Categories
                    Cells(R, 5).Value = ((myapt.End - myapt.Start) * 1440) / 60
    Else
    End If

Next

Set o = Nothing
Set ons = Nothing
Set myfol = Nothing
Set myapt = Nothing

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

However, when I use the code above it does not export the recurring appointments/meetings. I tried to find a solution online, however, all of the examples that I could find were setting up appointments, rather than making a list of them. Is there a way to include the recurring appointments in the export list and include all occurrences in the date range (1 week).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, when I use the code above it does not export the recurring appointments/meetings.

To include recurring appointments you need to set up the [Items.IncludeRecurrences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.includerecurrences) property which returns a boolean that indicates `True` if the `Items` collection should include recurrence patterns.

This property only has an effect if the `Items` collection contains appointments and is not sorted by any property other than `Start` in ascending order. The default value is `False`. Use this property when you want to retrieve all appointments for a given date, where recurring appointments would not normally appear because they are not associated with any specific date. If you need to sort and filter on appointment items that contain recurring appointments, you must do so in this order: sort the items in ascending order, set `IncludeRecurrences` to `True`, and then filter the items. For example:

```
Sub DemoFindNext() 
 Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace 
 Dim tdystart As Date 
 Dim tdyend As Date 
 Dim myAppointments As Outlook.Items 
 Dim currentAppointment As Outlook.AppointmentItem 
 
 Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
 tdystart = VBA.Format(Now, "Short Date") 
 tdyend = VBA.Format(Now + 1, "Short Date") 
 Set myAppointments = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).Items 
 
 myAppointments.Sort "[Start]" 
 
 myAppointments.IncludeRecurrences = True 
 
 Set currentAppointment = myAppointments.Find("[Start] >= """ & _ 
 tdystart & """ and [Start] <= """ & tdyend & """") 
 
 While TypeName(currentAppointment) <> "Nothing" 
   MsgBox currentAppointment.Subject 
   Set currentAppointment = myAppointments.FindNext 
 Wend 
 
End Sub
```

Read more about the `Find`/`FindNext` and `Restrict` methods in the following articles I wrote for the technical blog:

- [How To: Use Restrict method in Outlook to get calendar items](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/15/outlook-restrict-calendar-items/)
- [How To: Retrieve Outlook calendar items using Find and FindNext methods](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/11/outlook-retrieve-calendar-items/)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
Private Sub Outlook_Vba_Get_Calendar_Item_Appoinments()
    Dim oWorkbook As Workbook, Calendar_To_Excel_File As String
    Dim oOutlook_Calendar As Outlook.Folder, oCalendar_Items As Outlook.Items
    Dim oCalendarAppointment As Outlook.AppointmentItem
    Dim iRow As Double

    iRow = 1

    'Change path of the Target File name if required
    Calendar_To_Excel_File = "C:\Users\ryans\Desktop\Outlook.xlsb"
    'Check if Output File already exists
    'If VBA.Dir(Calendar_To_Excel_File) = "" Then
        'To Create New Workbook
    '    Set oWorkbook = Workbooks.Add
        'oWorkbook.SaveAs Calendar_To_Excel_File
   ' Else
        'To Refer Already Created Workbook
    Set oWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(Calendar_To_Excel_File)
    'End If
    
    'Get object reference for Outlook Calendar folder
    Set oOutlook_Calendar = Outlook.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
    Set oCalendar_Items = oOutlook_Calendar.Items
    
    'Loop Thru Each Items in Outlook Calendar
    For Each oCalendarAppointment In oCalendar_Items
        oWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, 1) = oOutlook_Calendar.FolderPath
        oWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, 2) = oCalendarAppointment.Start
        oWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, 3) = oCalendarAppointment.End
        oWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, 4) = oCalendarAppointment.Subject
        oWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, 5) = oCalendarAppointment.Location
        oWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, 6) = oCalendarAppointment.Duration
        oWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, 7) = oCalendarAppointment.Size
        'oWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(irow, 8) = oCalendarAppointment.Body
        iRow = iRow + 1
    Next

    'Save Excel Workbook With Calendar Appointments
    oWorkbook.Save
    oWorkbook.Close False  'Close Workbook without any Warning
    MsgBox "Outlook Calendar Appointments Downloaded To:" & Calendar_To_Excel_File

End Sub
```